# type/class __repr__ formatter for Python objects

Tags: python, formatting

I am building a list of Python objects that I use fairly regularly that have a length property, (len, '**len**') and I was trying to determine the best way to simplify the type/class formatter that the object uses.  For example:
 type([]), returns "< type 'list'>" and type(collections.Counter()) returns "< class 'collections.Counter'> "

I had assumed that the formatter that was used could be accessed simply and the extraneous information removed to facility a particular documentation format that I prefer.  In this situation, I had hoped to be able to remove '< type ... >' or '< class ... >' from the resultant output.  The kludge that I have come up with entails parsing the string into its components and returning the portion I want.  To ensure generality, for objects that I may not currently use, I had hoped for a better solution.

Insights regarding options to this issue, or more general comments would be appreciated.  The line in question is flagged with a comment.  Apologies, if I am not supposed to included doc information with posted scripts.

```
"""
Script:   empty_tests.py
Modified: 2015-05-25
Purpose:
  checks on objects that I use, that have a __len__ property
Notes:
- collections.OrderedDictionary and other classes in collections behave
  in a similar fashion
- for NumPy arrays, use size property rather than __len__
"""
import numpy as np
import collections
c0 = collections.Counter()
c1 = collections.Counter([0])
objs = [ [],[1],(),(1),{},{1:"one"},"","1",None,True,1,False,0,c0,c1 ]
is_empty = [ True  if not i else False for i in objs ]
t = [ type(i).__name__ for i in objs ]            # correct based on comment
#t = [str(type(i)).split("\'")[1] for i in objs ] # line in question
print("\n{:<15} {:<6} {:<10}".format("Object","Empty","Type"))
for i in range(len(objs)):
    print("{:<15} {:<6} {:<10s}".format(objs[i],str(is_empty[i]),t[i]))
```

Output with the above...the commented out line worked

```
Object          Empty  Type      
[]              True   list      
[1]             False  list      
()              True   tuple     
1               False  int       
{}              True   dict      
{1: 'one'}      False  dict      
                True   str   
.... etc
```

I have tried ....

```
>>> type([])
<type 'type'>
>>> repr(type([]))
<type 'list'>"
>>> str(type([]))
<type 'list'>"
>>> print str(type([])), repr(type([]))
<type 'list'> <type 'list'>
>>>
```

EDIT
the "**name**" property wasn't listed where I thought it would be, so if the object has a "**format**" property, check there.

```
>>> help(type(object).__format__)
Help on method_descriptor:
__format__(...)
    default object formatter
>>> dir(type(object).__format__)
    ['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__',
     '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__name__', 
     '__new__', '__objclass__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
     '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
    >>>
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to find the name of an object's type? What's wrong with `type(obj).__name__`?

Comment: @Gareth your edited comment has sent me in the right direction...it is buried in dir(object.__format__) I was looking in dir(object) for magic methods.  I will edit the code to reflect this.  Post this as an answer especially where this is documented, I looked for the obvious and didn't find it. Must have been looking in the wrong place

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `dir` to show you all the special methods ("[The resulting list is not necessarily complete](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)"). The right place to look is the [Data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) section of the Python Language Reference.

Comment: Excellent Gareth...I have edited the question so those that follow don't waste the time that I did finding the now obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in comments, but for completeness:

1. The name of a class is given by its `__name__` attribute.
2. It's not a good idea to rely on `dir` to show you all the special methods and attributes. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) you'll see that it says:

   > The resulting list is not necessarily complete.

   The place to look for documentation on special methods is the [Data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) section of the Python Language Reference.
3. Python 3.3 added `__qualname__`, which gives the [qualified name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/), which is more informative than `__name__` for nested class definitions.
4. `__name__` doesn't include the module name, so `collections.Counter.__name__` is just `"Counter"`. If you want to prepend the module name, find it using the `__module__` attribute.
5. `True if not i else False` is a long-winded way to write `not i`.
6. If possible, iterate over objects, not over indexes. Instead of:

   ```
   is_empty = [ True  if not i else False for i in objs ]
   t = [ type(i).__name__ for i in objs ]
   for i in range(len(objs)):
       print("{:<15} {:<6} {:<10s}".format(objs[i],str(is_empty[i]),t[i]))
   ```

   write:

   ```
   for obj in objs:
       print("{!r:15} {!r:6} {:10}".format(obj, not obj, type(obj).__name__))
   ```

Comment: Many thanks for the additional tips.  I will have to keep an eye on # 4 in particular.